# Angularjs have a button that adds text to an input textfield already in use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that has a textfield where you can write a message, but I want to give the user a set of tokens to ease the typing of those tokens.
For this I want to have a set of buttons that when clicked they add their respective token to the message, so if i have:

```
<button>name</button>
<button>product_description</button>
<input ng-model = "message"></input>
```

And in the input if Im writing "Hi," and I click "name" the input changes to "hi, {{name}}" so i can continue writing "Hi, {{name}}, we present you" and when I click the other button the exact same thing happens but with "product_description" like: "Hi, {{name}}, we present you{{product_description}}".
anThis way the user can write his/her message and personalize it with my set of tokens without him/her writing said tokens.

### Note:

I want to send the curly braces for later processing, the button will add to the text of the input field: '{{' + button_val + '}}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **ng-click** attribute for ***button*** tag, you can make a function call that would append the value to the model value set by the input field.

```js
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.input = '';
  $scope.name = '';

  $scope.addName = function(name) {
    $scope.name = ' user';
    $scope.input = $scope.input + $scope.name;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input" />
    <button ng-click="addName()">User</button>
    <h1>{{input}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) you can achieve required functionality.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-click-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

**protractor.js**

```
it('should check ng-click', function() {
  expect(element(by.binding('count')).getText()).toMatch('0');
  element(by.css('button')).click();
  expect(element(by.binding('count')).getText()).toMatch('1');
});
```

here is the link  of [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)